# Nested div-container gets bigger then parent element

Tags: css

I just tried to create nested elements, but the inner element (subcategory) gets always bigger, then the parent element (category).

Please have a look at this JSFiddle:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/d7vhpcmt/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <section class="category boxed">
        <section class="box_1"><header class="trigger trigger_aktiv"><h2>Category</h2></header>
            <div class="content">
                <section class="box_1 boxed"><header class="trigger"><h2>Subcategory</h2></header>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>  
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.category {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; }
    .category a {
        color: #262626; 
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 100%; }
    .category h1 {
        font-size: 2.0em;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: #262626;
        letter-spacing: -1px; }

.box_1 {
    background-color: #E9E9E9; 
    margin-top: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; }
    .box_1:hover {
        background-color: #eee; }
    .box_1 header {
        padding: 5px 0 0 50px; }
    .box_1 .content { 
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        height:100%; 
        padding: 0.2em 0 0 0;  }
        .box_1 .content p { margin: 0.5em 0.8em; }
        .box_1 .content h3 { 
            font-size: 1.2em !important;
            margin-left: 0.3em; }   
        .box_1 .content .box_1 {
            margin: 5px; }
```

Comment: Try - http://jsfiddle.net/d7vhpcmt/1/

Comment: But subcategroy should be as wide as the article-container below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have given `.box_1` it a width of 100% and `.content .box_1` and margin of 5px;  this means your box is going to be 100% + 10px - instead of using margin try add padding to the parent container, this way you don't need to keep adding 5px margin to all it's children:

```
.box_1 .content {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0.2em 5px 0 5px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d7vhpcmt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worry about `IE8` then use `calc` in your `box_1` class.

```
.box_1 {
background-color: #E9E9E9; 
margin-top: 5px; 
border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
display: block;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7vhpcmt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
.box_1 .content .box_1 {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

You are applying a `margin` around the entire section containing the Subcategori. Just edit in this way:

```
.box_1 .content .box_1 {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

In order to remove the margin right and left.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7vhpcmt/).